# Validate only when

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, validation

I need to validate a value's presence, but only AFTER the value is populated. When a User is created, it is not required to set a shortcut_url. However, once the user decides to pick a shorcut_url, they cannot remove it, it must be unique, it must exist.

If I use validates_presence_of, since the shortcut_url is not defined, the User isn't created. If I use :allowblank => true, Users can then have "" as a shortcut_url, which doesn't follow the logic of the site.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here we are always making sure the shortcut_url is unique, but we only make sure it is present if the attribute shortcut_selected is set (or if it was set and now was changed)

```
class Account 
  validates_uniqueness_of :shortcut_url
  with_options :if => lambda { |o| !o.new_record? or o.shortcut_changed? } do |on_required|
    on_required.validates_presence_of :shortcut_url
  end

end
```

You'll need to test to make sure this works well with new records.

Answer (score 0):

Try the :allow_nil option instead of :allow_blank. That'll prevent empty strings from validating.

Edit: Is an empty string being assigned to the shortcut_url when the user is being created, then? Maybe try:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_presence_of :shortcut_url, :allow_nil => true

  def shortcut_url=(value)
    super(value.presence)
  end
end
```

Comment: I found some bug reports, however, related to allow_nil

Answer (score 0):

try conditional validations, something like:

```
validates_presence_of :shortcut_url, :if => :shortcut_url_already_exists?
validates_uniqueness_of :shortcut_url, :if => :shortcut_url_already_exists?

def shortcut_url_already_exists?
  @shortcut_url_already_exists ||= User.find(self.id).shortcut_url.present?
end
```